# Show all the error inline in Emacs lsp-mode

Tags: error-handling, emacs

I am an Emacs newbie transitioning from Neovim.
In Neovim's built-in LSP client, I am able to see all the errors inline.
Please notice how every error is displayed on the problematic line immediately at the end of the line.
Here is a screenshot:
[image]

And now here is how it looks in Emacs:
[image]
Please notice that:

1. Only one error is visible, where the cursor is currently on.
2. By default, the error shown on the right side of the screen instead of immediately at the end of the line like in Vim.
3. The error is shown also below the line, in addition to the right side of the screen. This was achieved by this: https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck-inline.

How can I make Emacs behave like Neovim?

Comment: *Might* be one of the linked threads/docs throws an idea: [lsp-mode discussion](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/discussions/2892#discussioncomment-3832542), [related diagnostics](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/3279), [lsp-diagnostics-flycheck-default-level](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/settings/diagnostics/#lsp-diagnostics-flycheck-default-level), [lsp-ui](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-ui/).

Comment: I looked over your links. Only `https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/3279` (related diagnostics) seems to be relevant, but it is just a suggestion, it was not merged or anything. But yes, that is what I am seeking.

Comment: As a replacement for `lsp-mode` package you can also try to use `eglot` which is more lightwight and "modern". It also is inbuild in Emacs 29.

Comment: @buhtz Yes, I know all about Eglot. Thank you. It does not answers my question.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76352525/edit). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Didn’t OP use the images in order to “provide screenshots of the user interface”? I am confused by your comment.